# C++ friend function addition of two numbers

Tags: c++

I am a beginnner for C++ trying to write a programme for addition of two numbers using a friend function. Please help me as I am getting the sum of the variables initialized in my default construtor and not the one which I have requested from the user.

Here is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
class a
{
     int m_var;
     int m_var2;
public:
    a()
    {
        m_var=1;
        m_var=2;
    };

    friend void set(a obj1);
    friend void show(a ob);

};



void set(a obj1)

{
    std::cout<<"please enter the first number"<< "\n";
    std::cin>>obj1.m_var;
    std::cout<<"please enter the second number"<<"\n";

    std::cin>>obj1.m_var2;


}
void show(a obj)
{
        std::cout<< (obj.m_var+obj.m_var2);

    }



int main()
{
    a s;

    set(s);
    show(s);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `obj1` is a local variable in function `set`, when you call this function with an instance of class `a`, a copy of that instance is created "inside" the function, and the instance "outside" the function remains unaffected.

You should declare function `set` to take the input argument `obj1` *by-reference* instead of *by-value*.

**Change this:**

```
void set(a obj1)
```

**To this:**

```
void set(a& obj1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pass by value:

```
void set(a obj1)
```

It creates a copy of the object. Changes to this object won't be visible outside of the scope.

Pass by reference:

```
void set(a& obj1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void set(a obj1)
```

You create a copy of the object and whatever happens inside the method is limitied to the method body and isn't reflected outside the method.

Pass it by reference

```
void set(a& obj1)
```

Try not to create copies unless required. Change the signature of the other method

```
void show(a obj)
```

to

```
void show(a& obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `set` function has argument passed by value:

```
void set(a obj1)
```

so it modifies the temporary copy of your object, and the modifications are gone when function is exited. Change to reference:

```
void set(a& obj1)
```

and it should work better

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors. You will find them indicated in the code:

```
class a
{
     int m_var;
     int m_var2;
             ^
public:
    a()
    {
        m_var = 1;
        m_var2 = 2;
             ^
    }
     ^

    friend void set(a& obj1);
    friend void show(a ob);

};
```

Take argument by reference if you want to change original variable, otherwise a copy of this argument is being changed and no changes to original object after function returns are made:

```
void set( a& obj1) {
    std::cout << "please enter the first number" << "\n";
    std::cin >> obj1.m_var;
    std::cout << "please enter the second number" << "\n";
    std::cin >> obj1.m_var2;
}

void show(a obj) {
        std::cout << (obj.m_var+obj.m_var2);
}



int main() {
    a s;
    set( s);
    show( s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first your problem: set gets a copy of your obj because you pass it by value

but a lot of other hints:

friend functions mostly are bad design.

why not give set/get routines to your class and use these routines in your `void set(a obj1)` and `void show(a obj)` functions?

```
class A  // most conventions say classes have to be uppercase, objects lowercase
{
public:
    A()
    : m_var1(1)  // Also initialization of member should be done in initializer lists.
    , m_var2(2)
    {

    };
    int get1()const {return m_var1;}
    int get2()const {return m_var2;}
    void set1(int i){m_var1 = i;}
    void set2(int i){m_var2 = i;}

private:  // put private at end of class declaration since it is not interesting for class users
     int m_var1;
     int m_var2;

};

void show(const A& obj) // use const references to avoid copying
{
   std::cout<< (obj.get1()+obj.get2()
};


void set(A& obj1) // use reference to avoid copying that was the reason for your not working code
{
    int i;
    std::cout<<"please enter the first number"<< "\n";
    std::cin>>i;
    obj1.set1(i);
    std::cout<<"please enter the second number"<<"\n";
    std::cin>>i;
    obj1.set2(i);
}
```